# Does NetBeans 8.2 not support JDK 1.4 source binary format?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have installed NetBeans IDE 8.2 and found that it refuses to generate 1.4 format java binary. How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you register a 1.4 JDK through "Tools -> Java Platforms". And did you select that 1.4 JDK  as the platform for your Project?

Comment: no, I even don't have JDK 1.4. But previous version of NetBeans was generating 1.4 with java 7 without problems

Comment: It might be because this `-source 1.4` or `-target 1.4` is deprecated with newer Java versions (at least with Java 8). And I doubt you can actually create a valid 1.4 binary if you don't verify that with a 1.4 JDK.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to install a JDK, and compile from the command line using `javac -target 1.4 ...`.  If you really want to be sure that your code will work on Java 1.4, you should be using a Java 1.4 JDK.  (Yes, they are still available ... in the Oracle Java [download archives](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html).)

It would be advisable to use a build tool.

---

The other thing is that compiling for the Java 1.4 platform *ought to be* a thing of the past.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4):

> Public support and security updates for Java 1.4 ended in October 2008. Paid security updates for Oracle customers ended in February 2013.

If you are still using or supporting a product on Java 1.4, it is long past time that you stopped.  (It looks like the NetBeans team has done this!)